# How to join multiple tables after an internal full join?

Tags: sql, postgresql

I currently have a SQL where I return a table with the first instance of each string I pass on every like, and ordered by the product price (cheapest) and if the product is in stock. The result also should be just one product only for every product in the like.

So for example, the table below:

```
name            | price | id | stock | detail_id
goat milk 1L    | 100   | 1  | 1     | uuu-1
normal milk     | 200   | 2  | 3     | uuu-2
dark chocolate  | 300   | 3  | 1     | uuu-3
normal chocolate| 100   | 4  | 55    | uuu-4
```

I will get the return:

```
name            | price | id
goat milk 1L    | 100   | 1
normal chocolate| 100   | 4
```

The query I used to build it was this:

```
SELECT coalesce( t1."id", t2."id" ) as id,
           coalesce( t1."name", t2."name" ) as name,
           coalesce( t1."price", t2."price" ) as price
    FROM (
    SELECT id, name, price
    FROM public.product
    Where LOWER(name) like '% milk %' AND stock >0
    ORDER BY price
    LIMIT 1) t1
    FULL JOIN (
    SELECT id, name, price
    FROM public.product
    Where LOWER(name) like '% chocolate %' AND stock >0
    ORDER BY price
    LIMIT 1) t2
    ON t1."id" = t2."id"
```

The problem is, in another table I have another key which is called `allowed_to_use`

```
id_use | allowed_to_use
uuu-1  | true
uuu-2  | true
uuu-3  | true
uuu-4  | false
```

How I can join this table to the first one (join id_use with detail_id), to be able to show the product, just if `allowed_to_use` is true?

The desired result would be:

```
name            | price | id
goat milk 1L    | 100   | 1
dark chocolate  | 300   | 3
```

Comment: How are you expecting to handle the scenario where two milks or two chocolates have equal low prices? Maybe you want to return them all if they all have the same lowest price?

Answer (score 1):

```
SELECT coalesce( t1."id", t2."id" ) as id,
           coalesce( t1."name", t2."name" ) as name,
           coalesce( t1."price", t2."price" ) as price
    FROM (
    SELECT id, name, price
    FROM public.product
    Where LOWER(name) like '% milk %' AND stock >0
    ORDER BY price
    LIMIT 1) t1
    FULL JOIN (
    SELECT id, name, price
    FROM public.product
    Where LOWER(name) like '% chocolate %' AND stock >0
    ORDER BY price
    LIMIT 1) t2
    ON t1."id" = t2."id"
    LEFT JOIN allowed_to_use t11 ON t1.detail_id=t11.id_use
    LEFT JOIN allowed_to_use t12 ON t2.detail_id=t12.id_use
    WHERE coalesce(t11.allowed_to_use,t12.allowed_to_use);
```

Comment: I think this is exactly what i need, the only question i have left is, instead of using allowed_to_use = true, if i wanted to select the false ones, what i should change?

Comment: NOT operator - NOT t11.alllowed_to_use

Comment: It worked perfectly thank you, this is the solution. The last thing, if you could help me, is there a way to make it more 'clean', for example, imagine if i had like t1, t2...t20, i would have to make 20 left joins?

Comment: Probably, take my first answer and SELECT DISTINCT ... I corrected my first post, please test it and let's know

Answer (score 0):

One way you could do that would be with `exists`, include the `detail_id` in both sub-queries and wrap in an outer query that then checks if the Id exists and is allowed to use, something along the lines of:

```
select
  Coalesce( t1."id", t2."id" ) as id,
  Coalesce( t1."name", t2."name" ) as name,
  Coalesce( t1."price", t2."price" ) as price
from
(
    select * from 
     (
        select id, name, price, detail_id
        from public.product
        where Lower(name) like '% milk %' and stock >0
        order by price
        Limit 1
    ) t1
    full join (
        select id, name, price, detail_id
        from public.product
        where Lower(name) like '% chocolate %' and stock >0
        order by price
        Limit 1
    ) t2 on t1."id" = t2."id"
)t
where exists (select * from allowed_to_use a where a.id_use=t.detail_id and a.allowed_to_use='true')
```

Comment: This results in ERROR:  missing FROM-clause entry for table "t1"

Answer (score 0):

You can add more than one join in a sql but in your case you don't need your first join.

```
SELECT DISTINCT name,price,id FROM product JOIN allowed_to_use ON detail_id=id_use WHERE (LOWER(name) like '% milk %' OR LOWER(name) like '% chocolate %') AND stock >0 AND allowed_to_use;
```

Assuming that all products are presents in the 2 tables

If not use LEFT JOIN and decide what to do when allowed_to_use not defined.

Comment: The problem is that i want to return exact one match for every product i use inside like.

Comment: Yes it is, I want just to return in this case, the first 2 occurencies of the result. If the first two for example, are milk, i wouldn't return a response to the chocolate like.

Comment: Ok got it, so you have to join 2 times the second table, ie on t1 and t2, I write  my new solution